# Filter array of objects with another array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter, lodash

I want to Filter an array of objects with another array of object.The logic will be used in product search by category and color etc. This is my main Array :

```
products: [{
                            id: 1,
                              name: 'Product 1',
                              category: 'Home',
                              skill: 'Easy',
                              color: 'blue',
                              price: 100.00
                            }, {
                                id: 2,
                              name: 'Product 2',
                              category: 'Home',
                              skill: 'Intermediate',
                              color: 'red',
                              price: 120.00
                            }, {
                                id: 3,
                              name: 'Product 3',
                              category: 'Office',
                              skill: 'Intermediate',
                              color: 'green',
                              price: 190.00
                            }, {
                                id: 4,
                              name: 'Product 4',
                              category: 'Office',
                              skill: 'Advanced',
                              color: 'blue',
                              price: 260.00
                            }, {
                                id: 5,
                              name: 'Product 5',
                              category: 'Warehouse',
                              skill: 'Advanced',
                              color: 'white',
                              price: 321.00
                            }, {
                                id: 6,
                              name: 'Product 6',
                              category: 'Farm',
                              skill: 'Intermediate',
                              color: 'red',
                              price: 120.00
                            }, {
                                id: 7,
                              name: 'Product 7',
                              category: 'Space',
                              skill: 'Advanced',
                              color: 'green',
                              price: 150.00
                            }, {
                                id: 8,
                              name: 'Product 8',
                              category: 'Bathroom',
                              skill: 'Easy',
                              color: 'black',
                              price: 9.00
                            }]
```

The filter I am creating on the fly like this array.

[image: The filter I am creating on the fly like this array.]

The expected result is  to filter product data by multiple selected categories and colors.

I have tried the following code :

```
var filtered = [];
                  for(var arr in self.products){
                     for(var filter in self.selectedFilters){
                         if(self.products[arr].category == self.selectedFilters[filter].category && self.products[arr].color == self.selectedFilters[filter].color){
                            filtered.push(self.products[arr]);
                           }
                     }
                  }
                  console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: What have tried ?! , show us some code

Comment: Take a look [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/141943/filter-array-with-another-array), might give you some ideas.

Comment: Well for every combination of user_id and project_id in my-filter, filter elements from my-array. You may push all filter results to another variable. Finally remove all duplicate elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
var filtered = [];

for(var arr in myArray){
    for(var filter in myFilter){
        if(myArray[arr].userid == myFilter[filter].userid && myArray[arr].projectid == myFilter[filter].projectid){
            filtered.push(myArray[arr].userid);
        }
    }
}
console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: You can put a couple of array methods to use here - filter and some. They're available in all recent browsers, and there are polyfills available for the older browsers.

Comment: Here is the demo link with pure javascript. check this also  http://jsfiddle.net/LznL6tr5/1/

Comment: thanks man, But somehow I am getting ```myFilter[filter].userid``` as undefined

Comment: hai @NabaragPaul here you have to give a exact array. if this answer is usefull for you. please vote for this answer

Comment: Sorry for the uncleared question sir. I have edited the question with the exact Array and the code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```js
myArray = [
  {
    userid: "100",
    projectid: "10",
    rowid: "0"
  },
  {
    userid: "101",
    projectid: "11",
    rowid: "1"
  },
  {
    userid: "102",
    projectid: "11",
    rowid: "2"
  },
  {
    userid: "102",
    projectid: "13",
    rowid: "3"
  },
  {
    userid: "101",
    projectid: "10",
    rowid: "4"
  }
];

myFilter = [
  {
    userid: [
      {
        0: "101"
      },
      {
        1: "102"
      }
    ],
    projectid: [
      {
        0: "11"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const filterFn = (array, filter) => {
  let result = [];
  filter.forEach(element => {
    let keys = Object.keys(element);
    keys.forEach(key => {
      let values = Object.values(element[key]);
      values = values.map(x => Object.values(x)[0]);
      let ans = array.filter(e => {
        if (values.includes(e[key])) return e;
      });
      result = result.concat(ans);
    });
  });
  return result;
};
console.log(filterFn(myArray, myFilter));
```

Comment: Thanks, Naor, This works but I need intersected results only. In this case, if I pass this filter It should return
 [
  {
    /**id:2**/
    "userid": "101",
    "projectid": "11",
    "rowid": "1"
  },
  {
    /**id:3**/
    "userid": "102",
    "projectid": "11",
    "rowid": "2"
  }]
 I have updated my question also with exact array