# filter array of objects by another array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to filter array of objects by another array of objects.

I have 2 array of objects like this:

```
const array = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', sub: { id: 8, name: 'a3 sub' } },
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', sub: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } },
];
const anotherArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } },
];
```

and I want filter `array` by `anotherArray` and return items that is not exist in anotherArray and have sub.

So my desired output is:

```
[ { id: 3, name: 'a3', sub: { id: 8, name: 'a3 sub' } ]
```

**Note: I've done this with for loop but it work too slow. I want to do this with using Arrays filter method**

Code I have with for loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    let exist = false;
    const item = array[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < anotherArray.length; j += 1) {
      const anotherItem = anotherArray[j];
      if (item.id === anotherItem.id) {
        exist = true;
      }
    }
    if (item.sub && !exist) {
      this.newArray.push({
        text: `${item.sub.name} / ${item.name}`,
        value: item.id,
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: `Array#filter` also iterates over the array, just internally. Naively converting a `for` loop to `.filter` is likely not making your code faster. Please post the code you have.

Comment: possible duplication [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980942/filter-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-object/49981599#49981599](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49980942/filter-array-of-objects-with-another-array-of-object/49981599#49981599)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Like Felix mentioned, `Array#filter` won't work faster than native for loop, however if you really want it as functional way, here's one possible solution:

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', sub: { id: 8, name: 'a3 sub' } },
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', sub: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } },
];

const anotherArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } },
];

const r = array.filter((elem) => !anotherArray.find(({ id }) => elem.id === id) && elem.sub);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: Oh, thank you that works great! I have 300+ items in array, that is why I thought for loop works slow

Comment: thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for with slight modifications. I had 2 arrays, and needed to get the difference of the them in a 3rd array. I just removed the && sub part out. +1

Answer (score 11):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and then [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) since the later would return boolean instead of the element like [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) would:

```js
const a1 = [ { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } }, { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null }, { id: 3, name: 'a3', sub: { id: 8, name: 'a3 sub' } }, { id: 4, name: 'a4', sub: null }, { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } }, ]; 
const a2 = [ { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } }, { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null }, { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } }, ];

const result = a1.filter(({id, sub}) => !a2.some(x => x.id == id) && sub)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSON.stringify to compare the two objects. It would be better to write a function that compares all properties on the objects recursively.

```js
const array = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null },
    { id: 3, name: 'a3', sub: { id: 8, name: 'a3 sub' } },
    { id: 4, name: 'a4', sub: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } },
];
const anotherArray = [
    { id: 1, name: 'a1', sub: { id: 6, name: 'a1 sub' } },
    { id: 2, name: 'a2', sub: null },
    { id: 5, name: 'a5', sub: { id: 10, name: 'a5 sub' } },
];

const notIn = (array1, array2) => array1.filter(item1 => {
    const item1Str = JSON.stringify(item1);
    return !array2.find(item2 => item1Str === JSON.stringify(item2))
  }
);

console.log(notIn(array, anotherArray));
```

Comment: JSON key/values are **unordered**, so `JSON.stringify` is not reliable

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's solve this step by step.

To simplify the process let's suppose that two elements can be considered equals if they both have the same `id`.

The first approach that I would use is to iterate the first array and, for each element, iterate the second one to check the conditions that you've defined above.

```
const A = [ /* ... */]
const B = [ /* ... */]

A.filter(el => {
  let existsInB = !!B.find(e => {
    return e.id === el.id
  }

  return existsInB && !!B.sub
})
```

If we are sure that the elements in A and in B are really the same when they have the same ID, we could skip all the A elements without the `sub` property to perform it up a little bit

```
A.filter(el => {
  if (!el.sub) return false

  let existsInB = !!B.find(e => {
    return e.id === el.id
  }

  return existsInB
})
```

Now, if our arrays are bigger than that, it means that we are wasting a lot of time looking for the element into B.
Usually, in these cases, I transform the array where I look for into a map, like this

```
var BMap = {}
B.forEach(el => {
  BMap[el.id] = el
})

A.filter(el => {
  if (!el.sub) return false

  return !!BMap[el.id]
})
```

In this way you "waste" a little bit of time to create your map at the beginning, but then you can find your elements quicker.

From here there could be even more optimizations but I think this is enought for this question

Answer (score -1):

### OPTIMIZED VERSION

```js
const array = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "a1",
    sub: {
      id: 6,
      name: "a1 sub"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "a2",
    sub: null
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "a3",
    sub: {
      id: 8,
      name: "a3 sub"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "a4",
    sub: null
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "a5",
    sub: {
      id: 10,
      name: "a5 sub"
    }
  },
];
const anotherArray = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "a1",
    sub: {
      id: 6,
      name: "a1 sub"
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "a2",
    sub: null
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "a5",
    sub: {
      id: 10,
      name: "a5 sub"
    }
  },
];

const dict = anotherArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const { id } = curr;
  acc[id] = curr;
  return acc;
}, {});

const result = array.filter((obj) => {
  const search = dict[obj.id];
  if (!search && obj.sub) return true;
  return false;
});

console.log(result);
```