# Filter an object of array with another object of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, filter

I'm trying to filter an object of array `localcartArr` to exclude any object that's included in the `products` array, but it returns the same `localcartArr` without excluding this object:

```json
{ "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443" }
```

Which exists in `products` array, it works only with `===` operator, but doesn't work with the not equal operation `!=` or `!==`.

```js
const products = [
  {
    "_id": "60242abc209cbd32d8e85ec8",
    "productID": "5f6fd4f18b6f6b001799243f",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "60242b00209cbd32d8e85ec9",
    "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443",
    "quantity": 1
  }
]
        
let localcartArr = [
  {                
    "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {                   
    "productID": "5f6fd12a8b6f6b001799242f",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {               
    "productID": "5f7a5668a9baa50017d495e8",
    "quantity": 1
  }
]

let filterd = localcartArr.filter(local => {
  return products.some(product => {
    return local.productID !==  product.productID    
  });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [filter array of objects by another array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53603040/filter-array-of-objects-by-another-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

In order to invert "some / equal", you need to return "not every / not equal".

This is a principle of [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) in boolean logic.

```js
const products = [{
  "_id": "60242abc209cbd32d8e85ec8",
  "productID": "5f6fd4f18b6f6b001799243f",
  "quantity": 2
}, {
  "_id": "60242b00209cbd32d8e85ec9",
  "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443",
  "quantity": 1
}];

const localcartArr = [
  { "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443", "quantity": 2 },
  { "productID": "5f6fd12a8b6f6b001799242f", "quantity": 1 },
  { "productID": "5f7a5668a9baa50017d495e8", "quantity": 1 }
];

let filtered1 = localcartArr.filter(local =>
  products.some(product =>
    local.productID === product.productID));
    
let filtered2 = localcartArr.filter(local =>
  !products.every(product =>
    local.productID !== product.productID));

console.log(filtered1);
console.log(filtered2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is the same program, but simplified:

```js
const products = [{
  "_id": "60242abc209cbd32d8e85ec8",
  "productID": "5f6fd4f18b6f6b001799243f",
  "quantity": 2
}, {
  "_id": "60242b00209cbd32d8e85ec9",
  "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443",
  "quantity": 1
}];

const cart = [
  { "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443", "quantity": 2 },
  { "productID": "5f6fd12a8b6f6b001799242f", "quantity": 1 },
  { "productID": "5f7a5668a9baa50017d495e8", "quantity": 1 }
];

const filterEqual = (a, b, c) => a.filter(x => b.some(y => (c(x) === c(y))));
const filterNotEqual = (a, b, c) => a.filter(x => !b.every(y => (c(x) !== c(y))));

const filtered1 = filterEqual(cart, products, ({productID}) => productID);
const filtered2 = filterNotEqual(cart, products, ({productID}) => productID);

console.log(filtered1);
console.log(filtered2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter using the property you want to match on and exclude that not matching.

Some examples:

```js
const products = [{
    "_id": "60242abc209cbd32d8e85ec8",
    "productID": "5f6fd4f18b6f6b001799243f",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "60242b00209cbd32d8e85ec9",
    "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443",
    "quantity": 1
  }
];

let localcartArr = [{
    "productID": "5f6fd57f8b6f6b0017992443",
    "quantity": 2
  },
  {
    "productID": "5f6fd12a8b6f6b001799242f",
    "quantity": 1
  },
  {
    "productID": "5f7a5668a9baa50017d495e8",
    "quantity": 1
  }
];
// find matches
const myArrayFiltered = localcartArr.filter((el) => {
  return products.some((f) => {
    return f.productID === el.productID;
  });
});

console.log(myArrayFiltered);

//filter out matches
const notIn = localcartArr.filter((el) => {
  return myArrayFiltered.some((f) => {
    return f.productID !== el.productID;
  });
});

console.log(notIn);

// to put it together (for clarity)
// not that this is not super efficient if you have a large pair of sets
const notInX = localcartArr.filter((el) => {
  return  localcartArr.filter((el) => {
  return products.some((f) => {
    return f.productID === el.productID;
  });
}).some((f) => {
    return f.productID !== el.productID;
  });
});
console.log(notInX);
```